# Access 2007 : Error 2950 appears only in ACCDE

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database with all macros running fine when the file is an accdb format , when i make the accde a message appears saying command or action "refresh" is not available now , and then when i press ok it gives an error 2950 .
Please notice that i run the database from a trusted location.

Thanks,
Bishoy

Comment: By the Way , i just discovered that this only happens if i execute an open form macro action before i run this command , the other refresh buttons work fine in the Accde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is because the form does not have focus. You could try setting the focus to the relevant form after the open macro and before refresh.

```
Forms("Form1").SetFocus
```

Comment: But why would making it an ACCDE break it?

Comment: I don't know , but this solution works , thanks thanks thanks , Mr. Remou